# Stage simulation inconsistency

Tags: ros, simulation, simulator-stage, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I do have a question concerning the simulation in stage. I read in the documentation that no noise is being simulated, nevertheless my results vary. As I run my node (exploration --> which depends on position and laser scan) on stage, my results like the required exploration time differ highly. Does someone have an idea what causes such behaviors?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168206/stage-simulation-inconsistency/) by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS nodes run asynchronously with respect to each other, so it´s expected that the system is not fully deterministic. For example, depending on system load (and scheduling), messages might arrive in a different order in different trials, so variations in overall system behavior can happen. In most cases, these should be pretty small and much less than the effects of noise acting on a real system.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1